# WPF ComboBox - how to maintain selection when source collection changed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

How can I maintain selection on a combobox if the currently selected item is replaced in the ItemsSource collection? In this case the collection is an ObservableCollection and of course if the currently selected item is replaced the combobox loses its selection - nothing is selected.

The ComboBox looks like:

```
                        <ComboBox 
                            Name="combobox"
                            SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}, Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**I cannot simply set the selected item on the combobox manually each time as the collection is manipulated in another generic class I cannot touch!**

Thanks!

Comment: What is your criteria for keeping the selection? The index?

Comment: the item is only replaced not removed - i dont want the selection to change

Comment: When you replace one item, then the old item IS removed and the new one is added. So, the previously selected item is not present in the collection any more. At its position, there is a new item. Do you want that new item to be selected? If so, please show us the code where you replace the item.

Comment: @Daniel yes that is what is happening, yes I do want the new item selected, the code is not special it is like: myCollection.Remove(oldItem); myCollection.Add(newItem);

Answer (score 1):

you bind the selectedVaule to your Id Property. so if you want the new added Item to be the selected one, just set your Id property to the new Item and call OnPropertyChanged("Id")

```
myCollection.Remove(oldItem);
myCollection.Add(newItem);
Id = newItem;
OnPropertyChanged("Id")
```

Comment: I agree with blindmeis, the selected item should be part of your viewmodel and should handle the property change / collection change event.

Comment: Yes the problem was I cannot see my combobox from the the code that manipulates the data collections is - while I could expose it that is against our design principles - we need to keep the data manipulation separate from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to select the new item:

```
combobox.SelectedItem = newItem;
```

UPDATE:
If the `combobox` is unknown to the part of the code that replaces the item, you need to do something like the following:

- Subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of your collection.
- When the event is fired and it says that a new item was added, execute the code as shown above.

Comment: problem is the logic that replaces the item is seperate from the UI - I cannot see something like the combobox where the source collection is manipulated

Comment: I think I will have to subscribe to CollectionChanged - but I do not know from there whether the addition was from the current item being replaced or another reason..